No obtengo respuesta de fetch cuando inspecciono en la pestaña de network/response
Estoy intentando armar una base de datos utilizando mysql y nodejs. Cuando hago un get en postman me carga todo ok y luego cuando programo el javascript hago un fetch logro la comunicacion pero no recibo respuesta en la pestaña de response.
async function getArticulosAll(){
  const res = fetch("http://localhost:4000/productos");
}
    


const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const database = require("./database");
const cors = require("cors")


const app = express();
app.set("port",4000);
app.listen(app.get("port"));


app.use(cors({
    origin: ["http://127.0.0.1:5500","http://127.0.0.1:5501"]
}))
app.use(morgan("dev"))


app.get("/productos", async (req,res) =>{
    const connection = await database.getConnection();
    const result = await connection.query("SELECT * from productos");
    console.log(result)
    res.json()
})



Hola Daniel. Imagino que te referis al DevTools del navegador. ¿Podrías incluir una captura con lo que ves?
